# PHP redirect, but keep the same url (to hide it from user)

Tags: php, url, redirect

is there a way to redirect in PHP to another server, but keep the same url, so the user is not aware of?

thanks in advance!
kriscom

Comment: I really hope not. Maybe instead of redirecting, you could load an iframe and have it take up the entire page, so it just looks like you've sent them to a different website without changing the URL.

Comment: You mean to keep the exact same domain name and request uri, but be on a completely different ip address?

Comment: @krzysiek: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into apaches mod_proxy module to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it might be easier to configure your server for URL rewriting?

- Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [IIS](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/05/31/urlrewrite-module-for-iis7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could "proxy" requests to another server, but you'll need to worry about urls in the response from another server.